# Send Image from custom Keyboard to specific chat

Tags: android

I made a custom keyboard which has images. I tried to send an image to a specific chat, but it opens **share with** which includes all chats. Here's my code:

```
public Intent createIntent(Context context, InputBinding inputBinding, String uri) {
    Log.v("inputBinding", String.valueOf(inputBinding));
    String[] packageNames = context.getPackageManager().getPackagesForUid(inputBinding.getUid());
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    sharingIntent.setPackage(packageNames[0]);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(uri));
    return sharingIntent;
}
```

Comment: which specific chat?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Only compatible apps can receive images directly. Telegram is one of them.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard.html#how_it_works

:)